# Cocoa Document Based Application

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-design-patterns

I am creating a Cocoa Document based application. My application is a simple drawing application that allows user to paint on a canvas and save the document as a JPG or a PNG. I would obviously like the user to have multiple unrelated drawings open simultaneously and work on them.

My application always starts with a blank Untitled canvas and lets the user paint on the canvas. Then the user can save the drawing as a JPG or a PNG.

My application would only have a "New", "Save", and "Save As" but no "Open" since I always start with a blank canvas and I don't have the concept of saving the drawing to my own drawing format and allowing the user to open the drawing later again to edit.

Is using a document based application a good idea. What should I use as the document type extension when I create the Cocoa Document Based application project in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're saving as JPEG or PNG, then the extension would be... wait for it... .jpg or .png. Seriously, is this an April Fools Day question or something?